# Property 'value' of undefined or null reference in Javascript/D3.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I have the following code (see further below) of a fairly large program.

I have a button which calls a script/method (updateChart()) to create a D3.js chart. If I initialise that chart with a static variable, the chart class works.
However, the class of creating the D3 chart throws the following error when I try to pass on the dataset which I create by javascript code beforehand:

`SCRIPT5007:Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference`

The question is: How can I get rid of this error and have my updateChart() method processing the dataset just fine?

The weird thing is that immediately before passing on the dataset variable to the D3.js class, I print the object out in the console. There, everything looks fine and for every property I have a value and the object is correct.

The thing I don't understand is how can it be that while the object is being passed to the D3.js class via updateChart() and being processed there, it appears to have null values assigned to its properties while in the line before (the console.log()), the object appears to be fine.

```
//Button to create a D3.js chart with a custom dataset called waterdata
 <script>
     $("#testButton2").click(function () {
        /////
        console.log("click update chart 2")
        console.log(waterdata); //--> print JSO fine and without errors
        console.log(JSON.stringify(waterdata)); //--> Prints JSO fine truncated in IE but without error
        $(".chart").empty(); //--> clear chart container, if chart already there

        updateChart(waterdata, ".chart"); //--> here somehow the object seems broken

});
</script>


//The method / line of the error as shown in console
function add_to_stack(data, year, stack_year, direction,   query_direction, categories, count, x_pos, y_pos) {

 var new_list = [], current_data = {};

var fill_colors = { start: "#054696", in1: "#587521", in2: "#587521", out1: "#e63e2e", out2: "#e63e2e" };

current_data = data.filter(function (d) { return d.Year == year && d.Direction == query_direction });
for (c in categories) {
    //Für jede Kategorie eine Row
    if (direction == "down") {
        //für down y_pos Subtraktion erfolgt zuerst
        y_pos -= current_data[0][categories[c]];
    }
    new_list.push({  // --> this is indicated as error line in the console
        stack: stack_year + "_" + direction,
        increment: count,
        category: categories[c],
        value: current_data[0][categories[c]],
        position: y_pos,
        state: current_data[0].State,
        year: year,
        fill_color: fill_colors[query_direction],
        x_pos: x_pos
    });
    if (direction == "up") {
        //für up y pos anschliessend addieren
        y_pos += current_data[0][categories[c]];
    }
    count += 1;
};
return [new_list, count, y_pos];
}
```

This is how the data is being created. The lower case variables are values which are created beforehand in the code. They should all work fine as when printed out in the conosle before passing that dataset to the D3 method, all values are being shown just fine.

```
//structure of the data
//created by complex calculation in dataSetCreation.js
waterdata = [
    {
    Year: "2016",
    Direction: "start",
    State: "31.12.2015",
    Wes_3J: wes_3J_2015_c,
    Wes_2_3J: wes_2_3J_2015_c,
    Wes_1_2J: wes_1_2J_2015_c,
    Wes_0_1J: wes_0_1J_2015_c,
    Mod_3J: mod_3J_2015_c,
    Mod_2_3J: mod_2_3J_2015_c,
    Mod_1_2J: mod_1_2J_2015_c,
    Mod_0_1J: mod_0_1J_2015_c
},
{
    Year: "2016",
    Direction: "in1",
    State: "reopened",
    Wes_3J: wes_3J_off_2016_c,
    Wes_2_3J: wes_2_3J_off_2016_c,
    Wes_1_2J: wes_1_2J_off_2016_c,
    Wes_0_1J: wes_0_1J_off_2016_c,
    Mod_3J: mod_3J_off_2016_c,
    Mod_2_3J: mod_2_3J_off_2016_c,
    Mod_1_2J: mod_1_2J_off_2016_c,
    Mod_0_1J: mod_0_1J_off_2016_c
}
,
{
    Year: "2016",
    Direction: "in2",
    State: "new",
    Wes_3J: wes_3J_new_2016_c,
    Wes_2_3J: wes_2_3J_new_2016_c,
    Wes_1_2J: wes_1_2J_new_2016_c,
    Wes_0_1J: wes_0_1J_new_2016_c,
    Mod_3J: mod_3J_new_2016_c,
    Mod_2_3J: mod_2_3J_new_2016_c,
    Mod_1_2J: mod_1_2J_new_2016_c,
    Mod_0_1J: mod_0_1J_new_2016_c
}
  ,
{
    Year: "2016",
    Direction: "out2",
    State: "Verz",
    Wes_3J: wes_3J_verz_2016_c,
    Wes_2_3J: wes_2_3J_verz_2016_c,
    Wes_1_2J: wes_1_2J_verz_2016_c,
    Wes_0_1J: wes_0_1J_verz_2016_c,
    Mod_3J: mod_3J_verz_2016_c,
    Mod_2_3J: mod_2_3J_verz_2016_c,
    Mod_1_2J: mod_1_2J_verz_2016_c,
    Mod_0_1J: mod_0_1J_verz_2016_c
}
 ,
{
    Year: "2016",
    Direction: "out1",
    State: "Abs",
    Wes_3J: wes_3J_abs_2016_c,
    Wes_2_3J: wes_2_3J_abs_2016_c,
    Wes_1_2J: wes_1_2J_abs_2016_c,
    Wes_0_1J: wes_0_1J_abs_2016_c,
    Mod_3J: mod_3J_abs_2016_c,
    Mod_2_3J: mod_2_3J_abs_2016_c,
    Mod_1_2J: mod_1_2J_abs_2016_c,
    Mod_0_1J: mod_0_1J_abs_2016_c
}];
```

Comment: You need to do a bit more debugging or show a more complete example ([mcve]). Try to run the code in a better browser that would get you a more accurate error message. Best guess is that the filter doesn't match anything so `current_data[0]` is undefined.

Comment: Thanks. There are some reasons why I had to keep this example as short as it is. I could however figure it out by now by creating the object another time from ground up.

Comment: You should really consider deleting this question altogether as there is nothing to learn from it for the rest of us. Hint: as it has an accepted answer, you may not be able to delete it as long as the answer is around. On the other hand it's a self-answer without any upvote... Hm, not sure, but please clean it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the object from the ground up again and rearranged the script import tags and the error went away.